# Can't connect printer wirelessly to linksys wrt54g using WPS

Tags: wireless-networking

I've already blown over 1/2 day on this.  I keep checking and rechecking my router settings and they agree with what the documentation says for my brand new HP4620 printer.  Supposedly I just tell the router to listen for connections and tell the printer to connect.  It fails every time!  Further, I have also read some opinions that when things are not configured correctly the linksys will disable WPS and it looks like that's happening as well.   Further, it's causing other wireless devices in my house to lose there connectivity until I re-enable WPA networking on the router.

Has anyone been here before?  This is driving me crazy...

-mark

Comment: You should not be using WPS at all. Ever. At least, not if you value the security of your wireless network.

Comment: this answer is NOT helpful, especially when this is the way the printer instructions say how to connect it.  as for security, I live in the woods with only a couple of neighbors so it's not as big a deal to me.  I just want the printer to work!